# Does ZeroMQ/czmq fail once creating too many [ inproc:// ] connections?

Tags: zeromq

I have a set of producers and consumers, both of which are implemented as `zactors`. The consumers bind to **`inproc`** endpoints, and each producer connects to every other consumer.

At one point, it seems that `ZeroMQ` cannot create any more sockets or connections <sub>( I am not sure which ).</sub>

Minimal working example:

```
#include "czmq.h"

void source_t(zsock_t * pipe, void *args);
void sink_t(zsock_t * pipe, void *args);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    zsys_init();
    printf("Max sockets = %d\n", zsys_socket_limit());
    int num_sources = atoi(argv[1]);
    int num_sinks = atoi(argv[2]);

    /** Create sinks */
    zactor_t *sinks[num_sources];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_sources; i++){
        sinks[i] = zactor_new(sink_t, (void *)(&i));
        assert(sinks[i]);
    }

    /** Create sources */
    zactor_t *sources[num_sources];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_sources; i++){
        sources[i] = zactor_new(source_t, (void *)(&i));
        assert(sources[i]);
        zsock_send(sources[i], "i", num_sinks);
        zsock_wait(sources[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void source_t(zsock_t * pipe, void *args){
    const int id = *((int *)args);
    zsock_signal(pipe, 0);
    int num_sinks;
    zsock_recv(pipe, "i", &num_sinks);
    zsock_t * transmitters[num_sinks];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_sinks; i++){
        transmitters[i] = zsock_new(ZMQ_PUSH);
        if(transmitters[i] == NULL){
            printf( "Source %d could not create socket %d because %s\n",
                    id, i, strerror(errno)
                    );
            assert(false); ////// Here's where it fails ___________________
        }
        int rc = zsock_connect(transmitters[i], "inproc://snk%d", i);
        if (rc != 0){
            printf("Source %d could not connect to sink %d because %s\n", id, i, strerror(errno));
            assert(false);
        }
    }
    zsock_signal(pipe, 0);
}

void sink_t(zsock_t * pipe, void *args){
    const int id = *((int *)args);
    zsock_t * receiver = zsock_new(ZMQ_PULL);
    assert(receiver);
    int rc = zsock_bind(receiver, "inproc://snk%d", id);
    assert(rc == 0);
    zsock_signal(pipe, 0);
    while (true){
        zsock_recv(receiver, "z");
    }
}
```

I ran it on linux with 30 producers and 30 consumers and it failed.
My open files limit is 6144.

Here's my output:

```
$ ZprocTest 30 30
Max sockets = 65535
Source 29 could not create socket 4 because Socket operation on non-socket
ZprocTest: ../src/ZprocTest.cpp:43: void source_t(zsock_t*, void*): Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted
```

Is there anyone else who has faced a similar issue or can shed some light on it?

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the socket-level fully-meshed grid scenario of **`( 30 * 30 )`** `ZMQ_PUSH` sockets + **`( 30 * 30 )`** `ZMQ_PULL` sockets ( each with just a single end-point ) to work on top of **`tcp://`** transport class, so as to isolate the root cause of the observed insufficiency? What was the results, isolated that way from kernel `inproc://` named end-point handling?

Comment: I have tried TCP ROUTER-DEALER mesh, and it fails as well.. I think this has something to do with the per-process limits, because when I run the producers are individual processes (as opposed to zactors) it runs fine.

Comment: How about trying to create the `ZeroMQ` **`Context`** with about a 30 `I/O-thread`-s and map using `.setsockopt( ZMQ_AFFINITY, ... )` individual socket provisioning to a specific, target-aligned **`I/O-thread[i]`**?